# JPA CriteriaBuilder with CONCAT_WS function throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, criteriaquery

I have the following CriteriaQuery that I use to filter orders.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<OrderReducedDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(OrderReducedDTO.class);

Root<Order> root = cq.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Customer> joinCustomer = root.join(Order_.customer);
Join<Order, Shipment> joinShipment = root.join(Order_.shipment);
Join<Shipment, Carrier> joinCarrier = joinShipment.join(Shipment_.carrier);
Join<Order, Payment> joinPayment = root.join(Order_.payment);
Join<Payment, PaymentMethod> joinPaymentMethod = joinPayment.join(Payment_.paymentMethod);
Join<Shipment, Country> joinCountry = joinShipment.join(Shipment_.country);

cq.select(cb.construct(
        OrderReducedDTO.class,
        root.get(Order_.id),
        root.get(Order_.incrementId),
        root.get(Order_.state),
        root.get(Order_.couponCode),
        root.get(Order_.totalDiscount),
        root.get(Order_.total),
        root.get(Order_.originChannel),
        root.get(Order_.branchOffice),
        joinCarrier.get(Carrier_.carrierCode),
        cb.function("CONCAT_WS", String.class,
                cb.literal(","),
                joinShipment.get(Shipment_.streetName),
                joinShipment.get(Shipment_.streetNumber),
                joinShipment.get(Shipment_.city),
                joinCountry.get(Country_.name),
                joinShipment.get(Shipment_.zipCode)
        ),
        joinPaymentMethod.get(PaymentMethod_.code),
        joinPayment.get(Payment_.paymentDate),
        root.get(Order_.createdAt),
        root.get(Order_.updatedAt),
        root.get(Order_.externalId),
        joinCustomer.get(Customer_.fullName)
));
... filters and predicates...
```

The part that's giving me trouble and causing a NPE to be thrown is this

```
cb.function("CONCAT_WS", String.class,
                    cb.literal(","),
                    joinShipment.get(Shipment_.streetName),
                    joinShipment.get(Shipment_.streetNumber),
                    joinShipment.get(Shipment_.city),
                    joinCountry.get(Country_.name),
                    joinShipment.get(Shipment_.zipCode)
            )
```

More, specifically, when I use the `CONCAT_WS` function. If I use `CONCAT`, it works.
This is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.NameGenerator.generateColumnNames(NameGenerator.java:27)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.generateColumnNames(SessionFactoryHelper.java:434)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeColumnNames(SelectClause.java:270)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.finishInitialization(SelectClause.java:260)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:255)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1026)
...
```

This is my OrderReducedDTO

```
@Getter
public class OrderReducedDTO {

    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    private Integer orderId;

    @JsonProperty("increment_id")
    private String incrementId;

    private OrderStates state;

    @JsonProperty("coupon_code")
    private String couponCode;

    @JsonProperty("total_discount")
    private BigDecimal totalDiscount;

    private BigDecimal total;

    @JsonProperty("origin_channel")
    private String originChannel;

    @JsonProperty("branch_office")
    private String branchOffice;

    @JsonProperty("shipping_method")
    private String shippingMethod;

    @JsonProperty("shipping_address")
    private String shippingAddress;

    @JsonProperty("payment_method")
    private String paymentMethod;

    @JsonProperty("payment_date")
    private Timestamp paymentDate;

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private Timestamp updatedAt;

    @JsonProperty("external_id")
    private String externalId;

    @JsonProperty("customer_full_name")
    private String customerFullName;

    @Setter
    private List<OrderProductReducedDTO> products;

    public OrderReducedDTO(Integer orderId,
                           String incrementId,
                           OrderStates state,
                           String couponCode,
                           BigDecimal totalDiscount,
                           BigDecimal total,
                           String originChannel,
                           String branchOffice,
                           String shippingMethod,
                           String shippingAddress,
                           String paymentMethod,
                           Object paymentDate,
                           Object createdAt,
                           Object updatedAt,
                           String externalId,
                           String customerFullName) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.incrementId = incrementId;
        this.state = state;
        this.couponCode = couponCode;
        this.totalDiscount = totalDiscount;
        this.total = total;
        this.originChannel = originChannel;
        this.branchOffice = branchOffice;
        this.shippingMethod = shippingMethod;
        this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
        this.paymentDate = (Timestamp) paymentDate;
        this.createdAt = (Timestamp) createdAt; //https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4179
        this.updatedAt = (Timestamp) updatedAt;
        this.externalId = externalId;
        this.customerFullName = customerFullName;
    }
}
```

What I mainly want to know is if I'm using the `function` method correctly. I assume I am because `CONCAT` works.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of debugging within Hibernate, I finally arrived at the root of the problem:

org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/tree/ConstructorNode.java

```
private Type[] resolveConstructorArgumentTypes() throws SemanticException {
    SelectExpression[] argumentExpressions = this.collectSelectExpressions();
    if (argumentExpressions == null) {
        return new Type[0];
    } else {
        Type[] types = new Type[argumentExpressions.length];

        for(int x = 0; x < argumentExpressions.length; ++x) {
            types[x] = argumentExpressions[x].getDataType();
        }

        return types;
    }
}
```

`argumentExpressions[x].getDataType()` was returning `null`.

I googled and found out that this could be caused by Hibernate not knowing the actual return type of the given SQL function (apparently it only knows the most common ones).
I then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285944/10587134) and implemented a custom `MetadataBuilderContributor` like so:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                "concat_ws",
                new StandardSQLFunction("concat_ws", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        );
    }
}
```

And on my application.properties I added:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor=ar.com.glamit.glamitoms.config.hibernate.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
```

After relaunching the app, `argumentExpressions[x].getDataType()` now returns a `StringType` and the `NullPointerException` is gone.