# hibernate 6.0.0.Final custom dialect not working anymore

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using PostgreSQL 12 and Hibernate 5.6.8 with a custom dialect like:

```
registerFunction("hstore_find",
    new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "(?1 -> ?2 = ?3)"));
```

When I try to migrate to Hibernate 6.0.0, registerFunction and SQLFunctionTemplate do not exist anymore.

How can I migrate this registerFunction to new method of Hibernate 6?

Comment: How to migrate is explained in the release notes/user guide of Hibernate 6.

Comment: i already read the migration guide here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/migration-guide.adoc but nothing about how to migrate old dialect...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source of standard dialects how they register functions?

Comment: According to the documentation the `SQLFunctionTemplate` still exists... I suspect the problem you really have is with the changed type system.

Comment: @M.Deinum on github i can see : //TODO -- re-implement. In 6.0 there is no longer a SQLFunctionTemplate class, so something change...In release not they explain that they change how to work with dialect but i don't find example...i will try by my own ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes i read the Dialect class to see how they register function and type but i don't know how to apply this to my case.. i will try...

Comment: According to [the javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/function/SQLFunctionTemplate.html) there is... That's weird.

Comment: @M.Deinum as you can see in source code this class not exist in this package: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/6.0.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/function

Comment: @M.Deinum It looks like the javadoc directory wasn't clean, I can also link to other classes that no longer exist or where moved to another location. That class doc is not accessible through navigation/search of the javadoc though.

Answer (score 2):

Without having tested it, I think you need to use the following in your custom dialect:

```
@Override
public void initializeFunctionRegistry(QueryEngine queryEngine) {
    BasicTypeRegistry basicTypeRegistry = queryEngine.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry();
    SqmFunctionRegistry functionRegistry = queryEngine.getSqmFunctionRegistry();
    functionRegistry.registerPattern(
            "hstore_find", 
            "(?1 -> ?2 = ?3)", 
            basicTypeRegistry.resolve( StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN ));
    // ...
}
```

It is possible `basicTypeRegistry.resolve( StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN )` can be replaced with just `StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN`.

Comment: ok it's registerPattern that i don't see...i will try this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me (Hibernate 6.1.1.Final). However, the function is added via `MetadataBuilderContributor` (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285944).

This code adds PostgreSQL JSON function `@>`:

```java
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                FIRST_JSON_VALUE_CONTAINS_THE_SECOND_FUNCTION,
                new PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor(
                        new PatternRenderer("(?1 @> ?2)"),
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        FunctionKind.NORMAL,
                        null
                )
        );
    }
```

One might need to adjust parameters of `PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor`, e.g. `FunctionReturnTypeResolver` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a **custom dialect in order to add e custom function is discouraged** see https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/migration-of-dialect-to-hibernate-6/6956/27

The answer from @tenpigs-pinget can be improved as follows with the help of the `FunctionContributor` interface (tested with Hibernate 6.2.x).

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributions;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor;
import org.hibernate.type.BasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class MyFunctionContributor implements FunctionContributor {

    @Override
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        BasicType<Boolean> resultType = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN);
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern("hstore_find", 
        "(?1 -> ?2 = ?3)", resultType);
    }
}
```

**Important** In order to get it working you have to add a file called `org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` in the folder `resources/META-INF/services`. This file must contain the fully qualified class name of the FunctionContributor class (e.g. com.example.MyFunctionContributor)

Thanks to this approach there is no need for a custom dialect. Check also the discussion under https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/migration-of-dialect-to-hibernate-6/ as it contains a lot of information about this topic.

**Side note:** I had to set `<property name="hibernate.jpa.compliance.query" value="false"/>` in my `persistence.xml` as otherwise i always got `StrictJpaComplianceViolation: Encountered non-compliant non-standard function call [jsonb_query], but strict JPA compliance was requested; use JPA's FUNCTION(functionName[,...]) syntax name instead`. Maybe there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate 6.2.7.Final :

1. Andriy's answer using MetadataBuilderContributor is deprecated (since 6.2)
2. Mark Rotteveel's answer is no longer valid because initializeFunctionRegistry method signature has changed (since 6.2)

Based on Mark Rotteveel's answer :

```java
public class ExtendedPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgresDialect {

  @Override
  public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
    super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);

    BasicTypeRegistry basicTypeRegistry = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry();

    functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern(
        "hstore_find", 
        "(?1 -> ?2 = ?3)", 
        basicTypeRegistry.resolve( StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN ));
    // ...
  }

}
```

Edit: fixed according to Dirk Luijk's comment. Thanks

Comment: There is a small mistake in your snippet. It is missing:

val functionRegistry = functionContributions.functionRegistry