# registerFunction removed from hibernate 6

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, migration, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-6.x

We are Migrating from springboot 2 to 3 which includes hibernate 5 to 6 migration

```
public class ExtendSqlServer2012Dialect extends SqlServer2012Dialect{
    public ExtendSqlServer2012Dialect(){
        registerFunction("datediffhr", new SQLFunctionemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER,"datediff(hour,?1,?2)"));
        registerFunction("dateaddhr", new SQLFunctionemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,"dateaddhr(hour,0,?1)"));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72013981/175554 is for postgresql and you can figure out sqlserver after all hibernate is a multi db ORM :)

Answer (score 0):

`Dialect` now has a method `initializeFunctionRegistry`. The direct equivalent would be:

```java
public class ExtendSqlServer2012Dialect extends SqlServerDialect{
    @Override
    public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);
        SqmFunctionRegistry registry = functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry();
        TypeConfiguration types = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration();

        new PatternFunctionDescriptorBuilder(registry, "datediffhr", FunctionKind.NORMAL, "datediff(hour,?1,?2)")
                .setExactArgumentCount(2)
                .setInvariantType(types.getBasicTypeForJavaType(integer.class))
                .register();
    }
}
```

You may find `registry.registerNamed` easier to use, or you may like to use a different `SqmFunctionDescriptor` subclass.

You can also use an independent `FunctionContributor` registered via SPI instead of extending the `Dialect`.