# How to register column type in new Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I upgraded Spring Boot to 3.1.4 which comes with new Hibernate as well, however I am getting exceptions while booting up:

```
 Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [order_num] in table [assets]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]
```

Thing is this columns are really defined as Long (and int in DB). I understand that Long might be a larger datatype but I need to fix this without changing the datatype on all affected entities. In the past, it was possible to use

```
public class MyDialect extends SomeDialect {
   public SQLServerDialect() {
      super();
      registerColumnType( Types.LONG, "int" );   
   }
}
```

However in MySQLDialect(800) there is not such thing. There is just `registerColumnTypes` which requires parameters I am not able to define correctly (`TypeContributions`?) Do you have some working examaple how could I fix this?

Comment: Could you also share your application properties file about hibernate configuration part ?

Comment: also have you tried some migrations from [hibernate-6-0-0-final-custom-dialect-not-working-anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013981/hibernate-6-0-0-final-custom-dialect-not-working-anymore)